# Use form param in jsp page before submiting it

Tags: java, forms, jsp

i want to use parameter choosen in a drop down list in my form,
in my jsp code  (inside the page), before i submit the form?
is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not with JSP. JavaScript can do that, but that's disablable/hackable/spoofable by enduser. Can you afford that? Anyway, if you elaborate the real functional requirement in more detail, we can tell you about the better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is Javascript (JQuery,Ajax)